# Button to open link in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

I'm really new to Java and Kotlin, basically also new to Android Studio.

**I was trying to make a simple app which when clicked on, takes to a link.** Like in Android studio, an empty activity and Java language chosen. In the design just a button in middle, and when pressed a link to YouTube opens. Simple.

**I used countless codes I found online but always had several errors in the code or building the APK.**

Can someone tell me how do I make it, **give me the code maybe to put in xml and main activity?** I'd be really thankful. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough :(

EDIT: By code I mean, something I can copy from here and just paste in the xml and main activity, sorry I'm just experimenting and I'm new to stack overflow too!

Comment: Copying random code from the internet does not work. you need to understand what you are doing. This takes some time to learn.

Comment: Any place where I can start learning from? Tutorials on YouTube kind of confuse me. Any resource or anything will be helpful, Thanks.

Comment: Start with plain Java and when you feel comfortable with it, go to the Android documentation.

Comment: I'll try, thank you! ^-^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an example app for you. Just clone the repository or download it, import into android studio and build it.

https://github.com/Farbklex/openUrlExample

I kept it fairly simple. The `activity_main.xml` file contains the layout. It uses a `ConstraintLayout` to arrange the elements.
The text input is handled by the `TextInputLayout` and `TextInputEditText` which are from the [Material Design library](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started). Those are used to make it look a little better.

The `MainActivity` looks for the `EditText` and `Button` and wires them up with logic.
When the Button is clicked, the `onOpenUrlButtonClicked` method is called. It then checks the `EditText` for input and tries to parse it to a Uri. If it can be parsed, it then tries to find an activity on the device which can handle the Uri.

If the Uri can't be parsed or no matching activity has been found on the device, an error message is shown.

```
private void onOpenUrlButtonClicked() {
    String inputString = urlInput.getText().toString();
    Uri parsedUrl = null;
    try {
        parsedUrl = Uri.parse(inputString);
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to parse input to a URL. Input: " + inputString);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to parse URL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if(parsedUrl != null){
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(parsedUrl);
            startActivity(intent);
        }catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can't open URL. Did you enter a valid URL (https://...)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for the reply. I downloaded the zip file and successfully imported the project into the Android Studio, however, I got 5 errors which say "Gradle Sync Failed: Sync Issues Found" and it won't build. Um, I don't know how to send a screenshot of my screen here. What should I do?
.
Edit: If you feel like it isn't worth it, you're free to not reply. Just tysm for helping ^-^

Comment: @IbrahimPlays Check if updates are available for android studios and the plugins you have installed. Chances are, that this is causing compatibility issues. The project imports fine with Android Studio 4.0 on Windows and Mac.